# Ruby Factory method can not find attribute?

Tags: ruby, attributes, factory

The following Ruby code almost works. In the Mage and Warrior class, I gave it an attribute toon and want to print out the value, but it gives me this error.

C:/rails/11.rb:37:in `<main>': undefined method`toon' for # (NoMethodError)

What is wrong?

```
class Party
    attr_reader :member

    def initialize(occupation)
        member = create(occupation)
    end
end

class PartyFactory < Party
    def create(occupation)
        if occupation == :warrior
            Warrior.new
        elsif occupation == :mage
            Mage.new
        else
            raise "Unknown hero"
        end
    end
end

class Mage
    attr_accessor :toon
    def initialize
        @toon = "woor"
    end
end

class Warrior
    attr_accessor :toon
    def initialize
        @toon = "WAR"
    end
end

party = PartyFactory.new(:warrior)

puts party.toon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a party object. Within that Party object you created a warrior object, but you didn't save it to the object so it isn't accessible outside of the class.

For example if you do this:

```
@warrior = Warrior.new
```

Now you can access that warrior like so:

```
party.warrior.toon
```

EDIT: Make sure to add warrior as an attr_reader

Comment: Your solution worked thank you!! puts party.Warrior.toon. Doesn't that defeat the purpose of doing a factory? If I have to say what type to show the value on? It seems like ' puts party.toon ' should know what type it is and spit out the value of toon.

Comment: Since you're already passing the occupation into the PartyFactory class then it would make more sense to have the @toon property be in the PartyFactory class itself. It's a bit hard to fully answer you're question without understanding what you're long term goal with this code is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your `PartyFactory` class. If this class is in fact a factory, it should not inherit from the `Party` class. It should be an entirely different class that is responsible for creating parties.

I would change the `Party` constructor to take its member directly.

```
class Party
  attr_reader :member

  def initialize(member)
    @member = member
  end
end
```

I would change the `PartyFactory` class so that it doesn't inherit from the `Party` class.

```
class PartyFactory
  def create(occupation)
    if occupation == :warrior
      Warrior.new
    elsif occupation == :mage
      Mage.new
    else
      raise "Unknown hero"
    end
  end
end
```

To call the `toon` method you first need to create the party with the factory and then call the `toon` method on the party's member.

```
factory = PartyFactory.new
party = factory.create(:warrior)
party.member.toon
```